# Need to add class 'select1' on click event with these ids

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$('#select').click(function() {
  if ($('div').attr('id') == '1') {
    $('#1').addClass("select1");
  } else if ($('div').attr('id') == '2') {
    $('#2').addClass("select1");
  } else if ($('div').attr('id') == '3') {
    $('#3').addClass("select1");
  }
})
```

```css
.select1 {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select">
  <div id="1">
    //some code
  </div>
  <div id="2">
    //some code
  </div>
  <div id="3">
    //some code
  </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong in this code? I need to add class 'select1' on click event with different ids satisfying the conditions above.

Comment: do you want to add `select1` class to clicked `div` and remove it from previously added `div`?

Comment: You can use `event.target` like `$('#select').click(function(event) {
  $(event.target).addClass("select1");
})`

Comment: yes i want to add on clicked div and remove it from previously added div @vijayP

Comment: just for your reference i added background color to that class, check my code

Comment: just by using target, u can do it, and also you can add and remove class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('#select > div').click(function(){
      $('#select > div').removeClass("select1"); //remove select1 from previously added div
      $(this).addClass("select1"); // add select1 to currently clicked div
    });
  });
```

```css
.select1{
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select">
  <div id="1">
    //some code 1
  </div>
  <div id="2">
    //some code 2
  </div>
  <div id="3">
    //some code 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop to find child div inside main div.

```
   $('#select').click(function(){
    $('div#select > div').each(function(){ 
              if ( $('div').attr('id') == '1' )  {
                $('#1').addClass("select1");
              }
              else if ( $('div').attr('id') == '2' )  {
                $('#2').addClass("select1");
              }
              else if ( $('div').attr('id') == '3' )  {
                $('#3').addClass("select1");
              }
             });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with implementation is that `$('div').attr('id')` it will always return you the ID of first div it encounters while DOM traversal thus its returned value is *select*. So the no condition is fulfilled.

You can use [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) it returns a reference to the object that dispatched the event. then `$()` can be used to construct a jQuery object to use various jQuery methods.

```
$('#select').click(function(event) {
  //Remove previously added class
  $('#select > div.select1').removeClass("select1");

  //Add class to current element
  $(event.target).addClass("select1");
})
```

```js
$('#select').click(function(event) {
  //Remove previously added class
  $('#select > div.select1').removeClass("select1");
  $(event.target).addClass("select1");
})
```

```css
.select1 {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select">
  <div id="1">
    //some code
  </div>
  <div id="2">
    //some code
  </div>
  <div id="3">
    //some code
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a class to the div that was clicked. For that use `this` as shown below:

```
if ( $(this).attr('id') == '1' )  {
$('#1')removeClass("select1")
$('#1').addClass("select1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use each to loop through the divs as :

```
$('#select').click(function(){
alert('jk');
$('div').each(function(){
alert('l');
if ( $(this).attr('id') == '1' )  {
            $(this).addClass("select1");
          }
})
})
```

working fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/u9p0z41e/1/

Answer (score 0):

just for your reference i added background color to that class and you can do more customization as per your requirement

```js
$('#select div').click(function(e) {
  $('#select div').removeClass("select1");
  $(e.target).parent().addClass("select1");
})
```

```css
.select1{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select">
            <div id ="1">
             <a>First Div</a>
            </div>
              <div id ="2">
               <a>Second Div</a>
            </div>
              <div id ="3">
                <a>Third Div</a>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//function to remove the previous ones
function remove() {
  $('#first a').removeClass("select1");
  $('#second a').removeClass("select1");
  $('#third a').removeClass("select1");
}

//function to add class
$('#select').click(function(e) {
  remove();
  $(e.target).addClass("select1");
})
```

```css
.select1{
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select">
            <div id ="first">
             <a>First Div</a>
            </div>
              <div id ="second">
               <a>Second Div</a>
            </div>
              <div id ="third">
                <a>Third Div</a>
          </div>
    </div>
```